# Does this "apparently simple" linear system have a solution?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Does there exist $x \in (0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ such that for any decreasing $v \in (0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ that converges to $0$ (meaning, $v_{n+1} < v_n$ and $v_n \rightarrow 0$), there is $a \in (0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ with:
>   $$
> \begin{array}{lll}
> \sum a_n & =& v_0\\
> \sum a_n x_n& = &v_1\\
> \sum a_n x^2_n & = &v_2\\
> \mbox{etc?}&&
> \end{array}
> $$

[NB: I asked a related question before, which I then rewrote as the above. But I was recommended to post it anew to avoid invalidating old answers.]

Note that my question is equivalent to this: think of an *infinite* Vandermonde matrix with coefficients $x \in (0,1)^\mathbb{N}$
$$
V(x) = \left(
\begin{array}{llllll}
1      & 1    & 1      & \cdots & 1     & \cdots\\
x_1    & x_2  & x_3    & \cdots & x_n   & \cdots\\
x^2_1  & x^2_2& x^2_3  & \cdots & x^2_n & \cdots\\
\vdots &\vdots&\vdots  & \ddots &\vdots & \vdots\\
x_1^m & x^m_2 &x^m_3 & \cdots & x^m_n  & \cdots\\
\vdots &\vdots&\vdots  & \ddots &\vdots & \vdots 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
(where superscrits represent exponents and not just row position) and ask whether there is $x \in (0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ such that for any decreasing and convergent (to $0$) $v \in (0, 1)^\mathbb{N}$, there is $a \in (0, 1)^\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $V(x) \cdot a= v$.

I've found the following relevant paper:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357712000419

but it requires that $x\,$ satisfy $\sum_n \frac{1}{|x_n|} < \infty$, which cannot be true in the above (because $1 / |x_n| > 1$ for all $n$). The paper makes this assumption because it assumes nothing about $v$, so there's hope.

As always, thank you all for your help.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.8201.pdf
maybe this will help although there it needs x_i =1 for some i. Then  
maybe approximation argument,  but i dont know ?

Answer (score 0):

Wlog 0<x_1<...,x_n<...
What ifwe write it as :
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\sum a_n & =& v_0\\
\sum a_n (\frac{x_n}{x_1})& = &\frac{v_1}{x_1}\\
\sum a_n (\frac{x_n}{x^2_1})^2 & = & \frac{v_2}{x^2_1}\\
\sum a_n (\frac{x_n}{x^3_1})^3 & = & \frac{v_2}{x^3_1}\\
\mbox{etc?}&&
\end{array}
$$

There is also this result (theorem 2.1.4) by Polya
https://repository.nwu.ac.za/bitstream/handle/10394/2034/rabe_hermann%281%29.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Comment: i am also looking for an answer